# How to open a JQuery UI tab in a new window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the standard jquery ui tabs . My content in below in a div . However i need one of the tabs to open in a new window .

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. C </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">

    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind on tabselect event as per documentation. Check which tabs is being selected and do what you need to.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select